# Issue in Java Character reverseBytes

Tags: java, netbeans, encryption, character-encoding

I'm facing this weird issue. I use the `"Character.reverseBytes(char ch)"` method for the purpose of encrypting. It works fine, when running inside `NetBeans`. But Whenever I try to run it outside, it gives weird outputs.

I think the issue is that in two occasions, it use two different encoding methods (or something like that). The following code demonstrate the issue.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Encryptor {

    public static String encode(String in) {
        ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
            list.add(Character.reverseBytes(in.charAt(i)));
        }
        return arrayToString(list);
    }

    public static String decode(String in) {
        ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
            list.add(Character.reverseBytes(in.charAt(i)));
        }
        return arrayToString(list);
    }

    private static String arrayToString(ArrayList<Character> list) {
        char[] ch = new char[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            ch[i] = list.get(i);
        }
        return String.copyValueOf(ch);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException, java.io.IOException {
        String pass = "Password";
        String passEn = encode(pass);
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/pass.txt");
        file.createNewFile();
        PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(file);
        pr.write(passEn);
        pr.flush();
        passEn = new java.util.Scanner(file).next();
        String passDe = decode(passEn);
        String msg;
        msg = "Initial : " + pass
                + "\nEncrypted : " + passEn
                + "\nDecrypted : " + passDe;
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
    }
}
```

First I save the encrypted word to a file, then try to decode the saved word. This gives two different outputs in the above mentioned two occasions.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Do you have different JRE versions on your system and the one that netbeans uses??

Comment: You're not going to use this in a *real* system which needs any kind of security, right?

Comment: Wow, nice guess. Never though bout that. Do you know how to check it? I mean, in netbeans. I dunno much bout it..

Comment: @JonSkeet hehe...yeah, i mean no..say, just for fun...

Comment: What is your input and expected output

Comment: could you add also the following information: netbeans version, input + output when running inside netbeans, input + output outside netbeans, charset configuration of netbeans, charset configuration outside netbeans?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani have you tried the above code? it encodes any string..

Comment: @Anubis: It encodes any string to a quite-possibly-broken string which can include unassigned unicode characters. Really not a good idea.

Comment: @Anubis then what is your problem that I am not able to understand.

Comment: I think [this](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/8233) also talks about the same issue..

Comment: @JonSkeet are you saying it's not a good idea in the sense of encrypting or since it is not achievable ? can you give me a **simple** alternative. Because my app doesn't require much advanced security. But I though of something like this since i found it too easy. I don't feel like to go for too complex encryption methods.. :D.. But, Ok. Any idea is welcome..

Comment: @Anubis: I'm saying that this isn't *encryption* at all - it would be absolutely trivial to break. But even if you *did* want to just reverse the bytes of each character, you're not handling that data in a safe way. You don't have "real" text any more, and you shouldn't treat it like "real" text. See my answer for more details. There are plenty of simple approaches to encryption, which don't involve rolling your own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fundamentally, `Character.reverseBytes` is giving you a somewhat arbitrary UTF-16 code unit. There's no guarantee whatsoever that the characters you get afterwards will form a valid string - there could be "half" surrogate pairs, for example, or characters which don't have any specific meaning in Unicode.

More importantly, there's every chance that when you write the "text" to a file and read it back, you'll get different values - particularly as you're not specifying an encoding. There's a very good chance that the default encoding you're using can't support the characters you've ended up with.

Fundamentally, you don't want to do any of this. Encryption of strings should basically take the form of:

- Encode the string to bytes in a fixed encoding (e.g. UTF-8)
- Encrypt the binary data (please don't roll your own; Java includes plenty of crypto facilities)
- Pass the encrypted binary data wherever you need it to. If you *must* represent the binary data as a string, use something like base64 to make sure you can recover the exact binary data later.

Then to decrypt, you reverse each operation:

- Retrieve the encrypted binary data, which may involve converting back from base64
- Perform the appropriate decryption step (binary to binary) based on whatever encryption algorithm you used earlier
- Convert the result (still bytes) back to a string, using the same encoding you used at the very start

Treating arbitrary binary data as text - which is effectively what `Character.reverseBytes` is doing, in a very crude way - is a really bad idea.